# What is the best way to assign values to an parent item

Tags: html, radio-buttons, drop-down-list, jquery

[image]

I have list of customers on database which have collection of items(storage accounts).

When I select a customer , I can see all the items that are relevant to that customer as ticked.

Also , I have the option to un-slect(remove) and select new item(s) , And then click ,'Assign' and that will assign the new items to customer.

Now this looks ok, but , was thinking if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: Approximately how many customers and how many storage accounts are we talking here?

Comment: @J.Dimeo, Around 10 customers , and the storage accounts available are up to 1000. Not all of them need to be assigned , but they can select as  many as they want. All 100 storage accounts are not getting displayed at once but rendered using https://datatables.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
Adding a section for selecting specific users will solve your problem. But I don't know if you have some constraints on using this control as the development constraints are not said in the question.

Assign and remove can be done after selecting the checkboxes and clicking the respective buttons.

Answer (score -1):

An easy solution would be to show only selected accounts and add them one by one :

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYTTln.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Another one would be to add a search and filter on the accounts box of your solution depending on the use case.